# Windows Workflow Foundation - The deserializer cannot load the type to deserialize because type

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I have an exception I'm struggling to resolve here.

A legacy project of ours uses Windows Workflow Foundation. The XAML workflows are all defined in an assembly called `Project16.Workflow`. The default namespace for this assembly is however `Project16.Servcies.Workflow`.

The exception we are seeing:

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceCommandException: The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}LoadWorkflow was interrupted by an error. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The deserializer cannot load the type to deserialize because type 'System.Activities.Variable`1+VariableLocation[[Project16.Services.Workflow.OutcomeReportPublishOptions, Project16.Services.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' could not be found in assembly 'System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Check that the type being serialized has the same contract as the type being deserialized and the same assembly is used.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfLocationFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadLocationEnvironmentFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadActivityInstanceFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadActivityInstance.ChildListFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadActivityInstanceFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadActivityInstanceMap.InstanceListFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfActivityInstanceMap.InstanceListFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadInstanceMapFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadExecutorFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadKeyValuePairOfXNameanyTypenNMwwVNaFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.DefaultObjectSerializer.DeserializePropertyBag(Stream stream)
   at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.GZipObjectSerializer.DeserializePropertyBag(Stream stream)
   at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.DefaultObjectSerializer.DeserializePropertyBag(Byte[] serializedValue)
   at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SerializationUtilities.DeserializePropertyBag(Byte[] primitiveDataProperties, Byte[] complexDataProperties, InstanceEncodingOption encodingOption)
   at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.LoadWorkflowAsyncResult.ProcessSqlResult(SqlDataReader reader)
   at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreAsyncResult.SqlCommandAsyncResultCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceContext.OuterExecute(InstanceHandle initialInstanceHandle, InstancePersistenceCommand command, Transaction transaction, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceStore.Execute(InstanceHandle handle, InstancePersistenceCommand command, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.PersistenceManager.Load(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.LoadValues(PersistenceManager persistenceManager, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper, Boolean loadAny)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.LoadCore(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean loadAny, PersistenceManager persistenceManager)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.GetInstance(Guid instanceId, InstanceStore instanceStore, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.GetInstance(Guid instanceId, InstanceStore instanceStore)
   at Project16.Services.Workflow.WorkflowService.GetWorkflowInstance(Guid instanceId) in D:\a\1\s\Project16Development\Project16.Workflow\WorkflowService.cs:line 219
   at Project16.Services.Workflow.WorkflowService.<UpdateWorkflows>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Project16Development\Project16.Workflow\WorkflowService.cs:line 170
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Project16.WebApi.Core.Controllers.WorkflowController.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Project16Development\Project16.WebApi.Core\Controllers\WorkflowController.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

I believe the crux of the problem is:

```
The deserializer cannot load the type to deserialize because type 'System.Activities.Variable`1+VariableLocation[[Project16.Services.Workflow.OutcomeReportPublishOptions, Project16.Services.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' could not be found in assembly 'System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I don't think the problem is with a missing `System.Activities` that's referenced fine.

Now, what I don't get is `OutcomeReportPublishOptions` is a class defined in `Project16.Workflow` under the `Project16.Services.Workflow` namespace, yet looking at that it looks like it's trying to load it from an assembly called `Project16.Services.Workflow`.

In the XAML it's referenced like this:

```
<Variable x:TypeArguments="local1:OutcomeReportPublishOptions" Name="publishOptions" />
```

So I looked at the namespace and originally it was:

```
 xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Project16.Services.Workflow"
```

So I tried:

```
 xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Project16.Services.Workflow;assembly=Project16.Workflow"
```

However the problem still persists.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is because we renamed the assembly!

We moved from `Project16.Services.Workflow` to `Project16.Workflow` during a refactor and weren't aware of the binary serialisation employed by WWF into the instance storage.

I managed to hack a fix by creating a new assembly under the old name and putting a type forward in.